# Telling OwinHost on command line how to load a OwinSetup class with cwd outside project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

OwinHost is wonderful if your cwd is within your project root, i.e

`c:/code/myprojectroot> ../location/of/owinhost.exe`

As you are working from your project root OwinHost seems more than happy to auto magically find your classes as long as you have `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyOwinStartupClass))]` in your project somewhere.

However if you are trying to do this as part of a build script or something else where the cwd is not project root, OwinHost is not as nice to you and the command line args imply you can tell it where your project lives:

`c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root"`

However doing this, it constantly tells you nasty lies like:

`Starting with the default port: 5000 (http://localhost:5000/)
Error:  System.EntryPointNotFoundException
  The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.`

So I have tried the following:

- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root" MyOwinStartupClass`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root" MyNamespace.MyOwinStartupClass`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root" MyNamespace.MyOwinStartupClass,MyAssemblyName`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root/bin/Debug" MyOwinStartupClass`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root/bin/Debug" Namespace.MyOwinStartupClass`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe "path/to/project/root"`
- `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe "path/to/project/root/bin/Debug/my-assembly-with-owin-startup-in.dll"`

Nothing works, its like the ONLY way OwinHost will work is if you run it with CWD being your project root, so can anyone shed any light on where I am going wrong? as I am giving it the directory (`-d specifies the target directory of the application`) and I have tried manually giving it the DLL, giving it any permutation of the above.

So I am out of ideas any Owin-Whisperers who could tell me the right incantation to get it to do what I want?

Comment: Did you try `c:/not/project/root> location/of/owinhost.exe -d "path/to/project/root/bin/Debug" ` (i.e., without specifying the startup class) ?

Comment: Yep tried that too, I have tried every sensible permutation of the above with and without the startup class name etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the OwinHost [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/OwinHost/Program.cs), it has the following line:

```
ResolveAssembliesFromDirectory(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bin"));
```

Please note it uses **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()**

This calls a method which has the `AssemblyResolve` event

```
    public static void ResolveAssembliesFromDirectory(string directory)
    {
        var cache = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=
            (a, b) =>
            {
```

So, it seems it will always start the search from current directory. This is likely to be the reason for your issue.

Fix: Submit a patch to fix OwinHost ! (OR) write your own [Console app to Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

Comment: Already raised this but someone has responded saying that the directory bit should work. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/98